# 'IF' Conditional Not Working

Tags: conditionals, ifelse

I want to set up a conditional that when correctly running will post a 'widget' on the sidebar based on the entry. I have eight events (concerts) and three venues. On the individual detail page, I want the correct venue to show up, which is the 'widget.'

I have tried several ways, and I am getting nowhere. I am lost.

```
{if segment_3 == "opening_night_concert1" XOR "the_greats" XOR    "a_woodwind_affair"}

{exp:channel:categories style="linear" channel="sidebar_widgets" show="6" }
    <h4>{category_name}</h4>
{/exp:channel:categories}

{exp:channel:entries channel="sidebar_widgets"  dynamic="no" category="6"} 
    <a href="/index.php/site/contact"><img src="{widget_photo}" class="img-responsive img-hover" alt="{title}" /></a>
    <div id="widget">{widget_copy}</div>
{/exp:channel:entries} {/if}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to look like this:

```
{if segment_3 == "opening_night_concert1" XOR segment_3 == "the_greats" XOR    segment_3 == "a_woodwind_affair"}
```